# I want to get image from backend to frontend in MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I want to get image from backend to frontend in MERN Stack. all data gets about product also gets image title but images cannot render.
I want to get image from backend to frontend in MERN Stack. all data gets about product also gets image title but images cannot render
I want to get image from backend to frontend in MERN Stack. all data gets about product also gets image title but images cannot render
I want to get image from backend to frontend in MERN Stack. all data gets about product also gets image title but images cannot render

This is my frontend code

```
import "./Related.css";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getMovies } from "../../../Redux/Actions/MoviesAction";
function Related() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const moviesList = useSelector((state) => state.MoviesReducer.list);
  useEffect(() => {
    withoutReload();
  });
  function withoutReload() {
    dispatch(getMovies());
  }
  const [relatedProducts, setRelatedProducts] = useState(10);
  const allProducts = moviesList.slice(0, relatedProducts);
  const loadMoreProducts = () => {
    setRelatedProducts(relatedProducts + relatedProducts);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div id="related">
        <div className="moviesContainer">
          {allProducts.map((data, index) => {
            return (
              <div className="movies" key={index}>
                <img src={data.picture} alt={data.picture} />
                <div>
                  <h5 className="mb-0">{data.title}</h5>
                  <div className="cat">{data.category}</div>
                  <NavLink to={`/download-movie/${data._id}`}>View</NavLink>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="cancelBtn">
          <button onClick={() => loadMoreProducts()}>Load More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Related;
```

This is my Backend code

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const addNewMoviesData = require("../Models/AddNewMovie");
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "images/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post("/addNewMovie", upload.single("picture"), (req, res) => {
  const addNewMoviesform = new addNewMoviesData({
    picture: req.file.originalname,
    title: req.body.title,
    genre: req.body.genre,
    duration: req.body.duration,
    releaseDate: req.body.releaseDate,
    size: req.body.size,
    language: req.body.language,
    description: req.body.description,
    link: req.body.link,
    category: req.body.category,
    subCategory: req.body.subCategory,
  });
  addNewMoviesform
    .save()
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: can you share `getMovies` action?

Comment: export const getMovies = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/getMovies")
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "GET_MOVIES",
          payload: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response);
      });
  };
};

Comment: and the "GET_MOVIES" action?